# How do I place variables inside of a triple-quoted string literal?

Tags: python, json

```py
data = """
{
  "sender": "I want a variable here",
  "memo": "and here another variable",
  "amount": another variable here 
}
"""
```

I've tried using `f` in front of the string, and several other methods, but this is keeping me hung up.

Comment: since you have brackets in the string, you need to escape those. one way is with duplicate brackets: `f""" {{ your {string} here }} """'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to explain the question more clearly. What do you *mean by* "place variables inside of" the string? *What should happen* when you do this, and what does it have to do with the variables of your program? Also, what does any of this have to do with JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't construct JSON strings by hand as there are many intricacies of the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and your method is prone to errors. Instead, construct a dictionary first:

```
my_dict = {
    "sender": my_sender_variable,
    "memo": my_memo_variable,
    "amount": my_amount_variable
    }
```

then use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to convert it to a string:

```
my_json = json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you, and your right. I attempted that earlier but failed. I suspect because an error on my end. Because it is working now.